# Will starfruit grow in planter?

Tags: plant-health, fruit-trees, plant-care, planting, outdoor

Can a carambola/starfruit tree grow in a planter in the Caribbean?

A friend in Florida has a carambola tree in his backyard. Would this fruit grow in a planter?

The planter will be in a patio that will receive at least the same sun as the tree in Florida.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, but unmanaged carambola trees can grow to huge sizes, so learn how to manage a tree in a pot. Learn to manage both roots and branches.

Comment: Do you have some link on how to manage a tree in a pot? Will it grow fruit once I manage the tree in a pot?

Comment: Not a specific link, but google searching will produce lots of great results. Yes it will grow fruit, but it may take an extra couple of years than ordinary and you must understand a tree that is dwarfed by any means including by pruning won’t produce as much as a 20 ft tree will.